# Extent of G++ compiler optimization on non-commutative operations

Tags: c++, g++, compiler-optimization

I am concerned about the G++ optimizer's effect on arithmetic operations, specifically integer operations that are not necessarily commutative, eg * and /. This concern arose when I looked at a simple function in gdb that had been compiled with the -O3 flag set; it was all in all a better function, but it's form was completely different then what it had been with no optimization, operations had been removed, and some had been relocated. Here is a simple function with which I will demonstrate the crux of my concern;

```
int ClipLower(int num, int dig){
  int Mult10 = 1;
  while (dig != 0){
    Mult10 *= 10, dig--;
  }
  return ((num / Mult10) * Mult10);
}
```

This function simply clips off the base10 digits below digit 'dig'. My concern is, does the compiler consider things like the fact that math on integers is non-commutative? So, will the compiler  try to reduce **(num / mult10) * mult10** into **num * 1**, and of course discard the one?

I am aware that **volatile** will avoid this situation, but I would still like my code optimized as much as possible. So in essence I am asking if the gnu optimizer will understand that integer math is non-communicative, and further more how much of a concern optimization-gone-awry really is.

## also

here is the disassembly for the function at -O4, as you can see, the order of operations is fine

```
  13        return ((num / Mult10) * Mult10);
       cltd
       idiv   %ecx
       imul   %ecx,%eax
       ret
```

amusingly, the compiler generated a load of no-operations following the function, presumably as padding because it ended up so small.

Comment: Note that the volatile in the title did not refer to the keyword, but just operations that are volatile.

Comment: The compiler is not allowed to do that optimization since it changes the output. But it *may* do it for floating-point if you turn on `-ffast-math`.

Comment: I believe the term is *commutative* and not *communicative*.  The later is about communicating while the first one deals with positioning and evaluation of expressions.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'll make that change, thank you for the tip

Comment: @Mysticial Thank you for the info, it's good to know that the optimizer is on a leash of some length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the list of flags that `-O3` in g++ is equivalent to: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Now if you look carefully, there is also `-Ofast` which is defined as `-O3` + some other, especially `-ffast-math`. In description of `-ffast-math` you can read:

> This option is not turned on by any -O option besides -Ofast since it can result in incorrect output for programs that depend on an exact implementation of IEEE or ISO rules/specifications for math functions. It may, however, yield faster code for programs that do not require the guarantees of these specifications.

This is done precisely to ensure default compiler flags do not violate rounding error and other floating point standard specifications.

There is also a related question on SO, why don't compilers optimize `a*a*a*a*a*a` to `(a*a*a)^2`, the answer is the same. *(I cannot find the link atm =/)*

Btw, `Mult10 *= 10, dig--;` are you trying to lose people following your code? =D

*EDIT:* Another by the way, going over `-O3` has no effect. Except that some people say you might overflow some internal variable. I didn't test the overflow but I'm sure `-O4`  and `-O100` are equivalent to `-O3` at this point of writing this.

Comment: In retrospect, I probably should have just used a for loop, maybe like this :P  __for(int i = 0; i < dig; i++, Mult10*=10) {}__

Comment: And I was honestly tempted to try compiling with -O4 to see what would happen. Thank you for sharing this, I'll have to check out that web page before I ask any further documentation included questions

Comment: I mainly meant that comma operator. I am pretty sure there are quite some people that would get lost at this point.

Comment: As in they might think that I've overloaded it? or that they might not be aware of the operator's vast and various applications?

Answer (score 1):

Try it and look at the assembly

Optimization should not effect output, only speed.  Rounding should be maintained.  But bugs can occur, although much more rarely nowadays.

Generally issues are more likely with floating point.  2/7 with `float`s might vary slightly.

With `int`s it should always be 0, no matter what optimization,  even if it is multiplied by 7.